# how to customize subview that supports only landscape mode

Tags: iphone

i have one view with 4 subviews.

my application will supports both portrayed and landscape modes.

Among the 4 subviews,one of the view is support only for portrayed.

how can i done this.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Resolve my problem by rotating the screen

```
if (toorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        sub_view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadin(0));
    }
    else if (toorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        sub_view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadin(180));
    }
    else if (toorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        sub_view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadin(-90));
    }
    else if (toorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        sub_view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadin(90));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the UIViewController of the offending view. It should fix your issue.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    switch(interfaceOrientation){
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait: return YES;
        break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft: return YES;
        break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight: return YES;
        break;
        default: return NO;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u Aurun Aquila,i think you did n't get my question,can you please see my edited question

Comment: Ok, well add the method I suggested into the view controller for the subview that you're having trouble with. You should be able to figure out what to do based on the stuff I posted :)